# apa6: hyperref fails to recognize \subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks, apa6

I recently experienced several issues after some packages got updated. The one remaining is that `hyperref` doesn't recognize `\subsubsection{}` anymore when using the `apa6` class. The bookmarks in the PDF output are displayed as `<Untitled>`. The same is true for the example provided in the `apa6` documentation. I added a minimal example that also produces the erroneous bookmarks. All the other referencing (citations, etc.) seems to work just fine.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Sample}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University}
\leftheader{Author}
\abstract{This is a test abstract.}
\keywords{APA6}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Method}
\subsection{Materials}
Several materials were used for this project. Some of them were
\subsubsection{Paper-and-Pencil Instrument}
We used an instrument that we found to be highly successful.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the author of `apa6` redefined `\subsubsection` in order to add a period after the subsubsection's name. In doing so, however, he used the LaTeX kernel command `\@startsection` in a way that likely wasn't envisioned by the LaTeX team, and surely confuses `hyperref`.

In the following example, I have provided an alternative refinition of `\subsubsection` that resembles the one of `\paragraph` in the standard classes. A new command `\addperi` is used to add a period in a way that is compatible with `hyperref`. (As I'm not familiar with `\@startsection`, there's no guarantee that my redefinition doesn't break other things.)

EDIT: In case you are wondering why `\addperi` works in my redefinition, have a look at the description of `\@startsection` in section 61.2 of the LaTeX2e sources:

> **style:** Commands to set style. Since June 1996 release the last command in this argument may be a command such as `\MakeUppercase` or
>   `\fbox` that takes an argument. The section heading will be supplied
>   as the argument to this command. So setting `#6` to, say,
>   `\bfseries\MakeUppercase` would produce bold, uppercase headings.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}

\makeatletter
% Redefinition of \subsubsection found in apa6.cls
% \renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{1em}%
%     {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
%     {-\z@\relax}%
%     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\hspace{\parindent}{#1}\textbf{.}}{\relax}}
% Alternative redefinition
\newcommand*{\addperi}[1]{#1.}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\parindent}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\addperi}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Sample}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{University}
\leftheader{Author}
\abstract{This is a test abstract.}
\keywords{APA6}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Method}
\subsection{Materials}
Several materials were used for this project. Some of them were
\subsubsection{Paper-and-Pencil Instrument}
We used an instrument that we found to be highly successful.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the great advantage of online forums is that you can bypass the author of a package altogether.  but i've foiled your plot and mailed the author a link to this...

Comment: Since `apa6` is a maintained document class, please e-mail a bug report to the maintainer.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I'll wait if the OP does.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the definition of the `\subsubsection` command in the `apa6` doc class is, well, suspect.

Comment: I mailed the maintainer of course, but first I thought it might be an issue connected with my LaTeX distribution given the problems I had some days before already. Hence the post of the issue here...

Comment: The maintainer of `apa6` just informed me that the updated version is now available on CTAN and the new version indeed resolves the issue !